# Using Windows Environment Variable in Native Code

Tags: windows, winapi, environment-variables

```
// I have a permission to create a file to Program Files
const std::wstring sFileName = L"%ProgramFiles%\\aaa.txt";
HANDLE h = CreateFileW(
  sFileName.c_str(),
  GENERIC_READ,
  FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
  0,
  CREATE_ALWAYS,
  0,
  0);
// INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE with ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND
```

I expected it makes **C:\Program Files\aaa.txt** or **C:\Program Files (x86)\aaa.txt** depend on the Os' environment. But it didn't work.
What's wrong? How do I use environment variable in native code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explicitly expand the environment variables.  One way is using the Win32 API's [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-expandenvironmentstringsa) or [ExpandEnvironmentStringsForUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-expandenvironmentstringsforusera)

Comment: you would never call these functions for a single value you would call GetEnvironmentVariable.

Comment: @david - That depends entirely on the context.  The question wasn't "How do I find the value of an environment variable?" - I read the context as variable expansion within an existing string.  If the OP has a string that may or may not contain an environment variable ("%ProgramFiles%\\aaa.txt" per the example) - they would need to first write a parser to extract the 0..N variable(s) and then rebuild the desired string ... or use the functions I suggested.

Answer (score 4):

try using the [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188%28VS.85%29.aspx) function