# Using fopen with temp system variable

Tags: c, windows, file

I had some doubts about fopen...

Can i perform the following?

```
fopen("%temp%" , "r");
```

or do i need to use windows specific functions?

Comment: Does `"%temp%"` give you a filename, with required permissions for requested operation?

Comment: I don't understand your question , can you rewrite that?

Comment: `fopen("%temp%" , "r")` will try to open a file called... well.. %temp%.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788983/using-windows-environment-variable-in-native-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do directly (unless you want to open file called `%temp`). There is a function [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that does that:

```
char path[MAX_PATH];
ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%\\tempfile", path, MAX_PATH);
fopen(path, "r");
```

You can do that manually -- in this case it can be more portable:

```
char path[MAX_PATH];
const char* temp = getenv("TEMP");

if(temp == NULL)
    ; // Return an error or try to guess user's Temp 
      // directory with GetUserProfileDirectory or similiar functions

snprintf(path, MAX_PATH - 1, "%s\\tempfile", temp);

fopen(path , "r");
```

But there is a **cleaner** option for your case -- [`tmpfile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8x7sakw.aspx)

Comment: `temp = "C:\\Windows\\Temp";` is no good nowadays. It used to work under Windows 95/98 but from Windows 2000 on you cannot simply write into the C:\Windows directory.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use [GetTempPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppatha) function that simply expands your `%TEMP%` env variable.

Note, that starting from C++17 you can use [std::filesystem::temp_directory_path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/temp_directory_path)